# Problems with the Terminal

Tags: 20.04, malware

I recently had problems with Trojan viruses and malware on my Ubuntu 20.04, and I managed to vaccinate the system using clamav CHkRootkit RKhunter and Linux Malware Detector, but despite having deleted the infected files and recovering my account I still have the problem that the terminal does not The prompt appears, I clarify that I have already managed to prevent the terminal from closing, but there is a message that says that the process ended correctly with code 1, and that prevents the prompt from appearing, I have already made a backup of the things that interest me I would like to know if it is possible to recover the console because the rest works acceptably well, or would it be a better option to upgrade the Distribution to at least 22.04 so as not to lose my account with which I have had more than 7 years without problems and perhaps they will be resolved definitively? problems or perhaps a clean installation of a more advanced Ubuntu would be advisable? thank you.
[My actual Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcXQy.png)

Comment: Looks like an issue in your dotfiles. You can restore the original ones with `cp /etc/skel/.* ~`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the command but the problem persists, I left an image of what my terminal looks like in case that helps

Comment: The "terminal with only $ the" is a completely normal, albeit uncustomized, terminal. It used to be the default in old OSes. Now you just need to copy back working versions of the customization files such as .bashrc by following zwets' comment to get back the prompt you are used to seeing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1

1. Open your file manager. On Ubuntu, this is `nautilus` by default. It should automatically open to your home directory, `/home/username/`
2. Press CTRL+H to show hidden files
3. Delete or rename the following files:

- `.bashrc`
- `.profile`
- `.bash_profile`
- Any other similar files
- Your terminal will read `/etc/profile` as well, but if the malware was able to change that file, there are bigger problems

4. Your terminal should be reset now
5. Proceed with zwets' comment to do `cp /etc/skel/.* ~` to recover some default things like color and aliases

## Option 2

zwets' comment is nice, but you need a working terminal to run it in the first place:

1. Open your broken terminal. Ubuntu's default should be `gnome-terminal`, and accessible using CTRL+ALT+T
2. Right click anywhere in the terminal output area
3. Click "Preferences"
4. Select your current profile item under "Profiles." By default, mine is named "Unnamed"
5. Select the "Command" tab
6. Check "Run a custom command instead of my shell"
7. Enter "/bin/dash" for the custom command. `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc` might also work. Advanced users like programmers can try `/usr/bin/python3` for greater certainty in case the malware infected the dash shell
8. Close all terminal and preference windows
9. Reopen the terminal
10. Fix the files like before
11. Remove the custom command previously set in the GUI
12. Close and reopen the terminal to get back the normal prompt

## Option 3

1. Create another administrator user account
2. Log into that account and use its terminal
3. Do `sudo -i` to escalate
4. `cd` back to your original user's home directory
5. Fix the files like before

## Option 4

These are emergency options if your shell is broken from files in `/etc`:

- Press escape while booting, and select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" > "something (recovery mode)", or
- Press e while the "Ubnutu" option is selected, and use the `init=/bin/bash` trick
- Use LiveCD you installed Ubnutu from, mount your hard disk, and open a terminal there

However, a clean installation is certainly more advisable. This is the policy in large organizations such as Google. Once infected with malware, either the entire user account or the entire system needs to be wiped for security, depending on whether the original account was an administrator. Since something (your terminal) is still wrong with your system, you have to assume that the malware is still there, and can show anything to trick you into thinking things are "acceptably well." You should boot into a LiveCD, back up all personal non-system files you care about onto a *second* USB, then reinstall the system.

Comment: Thank you, step 1 and 2 worked but now I have the terminal with only $ the user name and the rest do not appear, is this normal?

Comment: I used $ cp -a /etc/skel/.* ~
why the original command $ cp
 /etc/skel/.* ~
It had given me these errors:
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/etc/skel/.'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/etc/skel/..'
by the way, I'm using the terminal that comes in PycharmCE

Comment: If the commands aren't working for the skel part, you can use the GUI. 1. Open the nautilus file manager. 2. Click "+ Other Locations" 3. Click "Ubuntu" 4. Open the "etc" then "skel" folders 5. If you don't see any files, make sure you used CTRL+H to show hidden files 6. Select everything and CTRL+C 7. Select "Home" 8. CTRL+V

Comment: Thank you very much everything is working very well

Comment: @CapoBugbler: I reread your errors, and it seems that the errors are because the original command did not take into consideration directories like /etc/skel/.config. As the error message said, cp -r or cp -ar instead of cp -a would have worked. By the way, on AskUbuntu and StackExchange websites, a askers usually thank answerers by clicking on the "accept answer" button instead of commenting, but you're welcome in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to asking questions in this system, I just accepted the answer, thanks for the clarification.